# Best practice determine passed parameter type in Restful API?

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I am doing my first JSON RESTful API in Java.

The front end will be AngularJS. For the Web Service, I'm using Tomcat 7, JAX-RS, Jackson, Jersey, etc...

I would like to keep the API as simple as possible.

e.g. I would query a user by ID as well as UUID. So I would like to use e.g. `/rest/users/{id}` and `/rest/users/{uuid}`. I would ideally like the back-end to figure out which is which rather than create separate API branches.

Since it's all coming from JSON, I assume I can not just let Java figure it out based on the type. So I have come up with:

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public User getJSONUser(@PathParam("id") String id) {

    User user;
    if(id.contains("-")){
        user = userDao.getUserByHandle(id);
    }else{
        user = userDao.getUserById(Long.parseLong(id)); 
    }       
    return user;
}
```

I notice that as an example, the Facebook API does this all over the place. e.g. `/{user-id}/albums` and  `/{page-id}/albums`.

Is there some trick I should be aware of that makes detecting these parameters easier? Or is FB encoding something in the ID itself? i.e. am I on the right track already. It's pretty cool how Jersey is able to figure out the calls based on MediaType. I thought there might be something equally as cool going on inside to deal with this...

Thanks in advance
Peter

Answer (score 0):

I assume that they are encoding something in the ID itself.

From a purely REST-point-of-view, `/{user-id}/albums` and `{page-id}/albums` are the same endpoint.